# Use of solver to minimise an vba function (instead of an excel cell wrt other excel cell)

Tags: excel, vba, solver, minimization

I want to minimise the function myFunction by changing the values of alpha. In this dummy example, I expect alpha = X (= 3).

To do so, I want to use the Excel Solver, and avoid copying part of the code in the sheet. This code is part of a Least Sqare Interpolator.

Thus I wonder **how to write correctly the Minimizer function - Solver part**. (the rest being correct).

```
Option Explicit

Private alpha As Double

Function myFunction(X)

    'myFunction , the variable is alpha
    myFunction = ( alpha - X ) ^2

End Function


Public Sub Minimizer()

    Dim X As Double
    X = 3
    Solver (change alpha with the value that minimize myFunction(X))

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what you wish to do, I think I've hit my english limits here. But in case I've understood you can use Excel formulas  within macros/sheet code like `var = WorksheetFunction.<excell function>(<parameters>)`. If I totally misunderstood, tell me and I'll delete this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want to do isn't possible.  The solver is designed for use in a worksheet.

If you decide that you are willing to place data on your worksheet, then you can set the solver options with `SolverOptions`, Set the target cell and cells to change with `SolverOk`, add constraints with `SolverAdd`, and solve with `SolverSolve`.  More details are on [Microsoft's Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196600(v=office.15).aspx).